# How can l set frames for 12 buttons with loop (programatically)?

Tags: swift, button, layout, uikit, frames

I'm trying to make Concentration game (with matching cards) and my task is to set frames for the array of 12 UIButtons with for-loop (I tried to realize it with switches, but it wan't right as my mentor said).

So maybe you can help me with this. The code added below works correctly, but l have to escape of switch and make it works with the help of for-loop and universal formulas.

```
  func setFrames() {
    for i in 0...11{
      var x = CGFloat()
      var y = CGFloat()
      switch i {
      case 0...2:
        y = 50
      case 3...5:
        y = (7/36 * view.bounds.height + 50);
      case 6...8:
        y = (7/18 * view.bounds.height + 50);
      default:
        y = (7/12 * view.bounds.height + 50);
      }
      switch i {
      case 0, 3, 6, 9:
        x = 1/18 * view.bounds.width; //20
      case 1, 4, 7, 10:
        x = 3/8 * view.bounds.width; //3/8
      default:
        x = 3/4 * view.bounds.width - 20;
      }
      buttonsArray[i].frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: (1/4 * view.bounds.width), height: (1/6 * view.bounds.height))
      
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Your calculation might be strange, they are not equally reparted? For instance, the `x` is quite strange, why `1/18` ? Why `-20`? I see the `3/4` is `6/8` (double of previous `3/8`).  For `y`, it can be simplified: `let y = 50 + view.bounds.height * CGFloat(i / 3) * 7.0 / 36.0`

Comment: @Larme I did as you say with Y and everything is perfect, thank you so much! If you have a minute, can you help me with X - I understand that something is going wrong, but l can't realize how to change it.

Comment: For instance, if you do `buttonArray[1].origin.x - buttonArray[0].origin.x` and `buttonArray[2].origin.x - buttonArray[1].origin.x`, It should compare the origin of buttons in your grid in the first line first and second, second an third, the space between them is not the same? (we have to remove in fact the same value of the width of the button, but it's fine). Or is the width of the view "special" and it's the same in your particular size? Are the button supposed to be center in vertical/horizontal of your view?

Comment: @Larme The width between buttons should be the same depending on the screen size. And buttons should look like this:
[B] [B] [B] / enter
[B] [B] [B]

Comment: You want to set 12 buttons with 3 columns and a 4-row grid layout according to your superview/screen size right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like so:

```swift
func placeBtnsIn(frame: CGRect, padding: CGFloat) {
    
    let numCols = 3
    let numRows = 4
    
    let buttonWidth = (frame.width - CGFloat(numCols - 1) * padding) / CGFloat(numCols)
    let buttonHeight = (frame.height - CGFloat(numRows - 1) * padding) / CGFloat(numRows)
    
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
    
    for row in 0...(numRows - 1) {
        y = frame.origin.y + (buttonHeight + padding) * CGFloat(row)
        for col in 0...(numCols - 1) {
            x = frame.origin.x + (buttonWidth + padding) * CGFloat(col)
            let button = UIButton()
            button.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
            self.addSubview(button)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code use it like so:

```swift
placeBtnsIn(frame: yourFrame, padding: 5)
```

Where `yourFrame` is a rectangle in which buttons should be drawn, and `padding` is the distance between button "cells"